# Disable variations on woo commerce if out of stock

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I use Woo Commerce on my site with multiple variations on one product. How do I remove or blank out a variation from being selected if I make the product 'Out of Stock'? I've tried using 'Hide Out of Stock' in the Woo Commerce settings though this made no difference.

Comment: This has everything to do with the theme you are using. It is possible.

Comment: Are you sure because the theme itself is designed around Woo Commerce

Comment: Yes, the theme is in control, that setting is specific and must be utilized by the theme.

Comment: This is totally false! A theme has no more control over how your site works than a plugin does.There MAY exists a theme that controls this, but you shouldn't go searching through your themes documentation for the answer. Most Wordpress themes are 100% compatible with Woo, and at the same time have 100% nothing to do with Woo.

Comment: @JimMaguire, it has no code which is usually an indication of no research being done before asking it and on top of it, it is asking about off topic subject.

Comment: I've tried Googling and gone through the whole first page inserting different bits of code none of which has worked.

Comment: I've also tried disabling that variation instead of being out of stock however the variation still shows on the theme and just says "Sorry, no products matched your selection. Please choose a different combination."

Comment: This is the exact issue I'm having. Say A4 is selected like it is. The next option shows 300GSM even though there is no variables for that... Ive tried removing them, disabling them. changing them to out of stock. Nothing works. https://i.gyazo.com/04cc644c0cbea4e241941a2c7550a6cc.png

Comment: user2634611 - You're question probably won't get answered now. On this site, once some idiot down votes you, basically your question gets buried and never answered. It does belong on the main S.O. site, [Woocommerce isn't technically Wordpress].

Comment: It hasn't been down voted though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve my own issue.

Simply paste the following into functions.php

```
    function custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold( $qty, $product ) {
    return 10;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 'custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold', 10, 2 );
```

Then change the 'return 10;' to however many variations you have.

**Please note this may slow down page loading time depending on your hosting.**